# curious behavior of set.seed inside function

Tags: r

Something i came across today that i don't quite understand. The setup is that i want to generate some uniformly distributed points in the plane, afterwards i want to assign each point an arrival rate. I want to be able to reproduce the same points but assign different arrival rates. I figured i could use the `set.seed` function for this.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

seed = NULL
no_of_points = 50 
interval = c("min" = -10, "max" = 10)
arv = c("min" = 1/80, "max" = 1)

plot_data <- function() {
  id <- 1:no_of_points
  # setting the seed here to be able to reproduce if desired
  set.seed(seed)
  x <- runif(no_of_points, min = interval["min"], max = interval["max"])
  y <- runif(no_of_points, min = interval["min"], max = interval["max"])
  # resetting the seed to give "random" arrival rates regardless of the seed
  set.seed(NULL)
  arrival_rate <- runif(no_of_points, min = arv["min"], max = arv["max"])
  
  data <- tibble(
    "Demand point id" = as.character(id),
    "x" = x, 
    "y" = y, 
    "Arrival rate" = arrival_rate
  )
}

ggplot(plot_data()) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y, size = `Arrival rate`))
```

This works fine when i set a seed and i get a plot like this, which is what i would expect

[image: With a integer value for the seed]

However when i have `seed = NULL` as in the example code i get a plot like this, where it seems that arrival rates are correlated with the x-axis.

[image: With seed = NULL]

How can this be explained? Additionally i tried to run the same code but not inside a function, but then i get expected behavior. So i suspect it has something to do with the seed being set inside a function.

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem with the code you have provided. The size of the points appears randomly distributed, as expected. Have you tried restarting your R session?

Comment: not reproducible. I say it is just seeing pattern out of randomness. A tail event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `set.seed(NULL)` is doing what you expect. In this case I think `NULL` is initializing the exact same random seed both times you call it. Therefore, the first random number generation after calling `set.seed(NULL)` (`x`) is correlated with the first random number generation after you call `set.seed(NULL)` again (`Arrival rate`) (but not the second generation of the first instance - `y`). In this simple example, you can see that the `n`th random generation after setting a particular seed is correlated with the `n`th random generation after setting that same seed again, and that using `NULL` and `NULL` is basically the same as using `1` and `1`.

```r
f <- function(s1 = NULL, s2 = NULL) {
  
  set.seed(s1)
  a <- runif(50)
  b <- runif(50)
  c <- runif(50)
  
  set.seed(s2)
  d <- runif(50)
  e <- runif(50)
  f <- runif(50)
  
  x <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f)
  
  plot(x)
  
}

f(NULL, NULL)
```

[image]

```r
f(1, 1)
```

[image]

```r
f(1, 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>